# How to change the global dimension in assembly of solidworks

Tags: global, solidworks, publisher

I have been modelling the parametic window in Solidworks with custom UI.
But in assembly, global dimension of part isnot changed properly according to input parameters of custom UI.
Other input parameters except for globa dimension work very well.
I want to know how to change the global dimension according to input parameters of custom UI in assembly.

Actually, I am gonna build the user-friendly model of large generator and I want to optimize the model size properly.

Thanks for your time.
Regards.
Yashine

Comment: There seems to be a lot of detail missing here. What exactly are you changing? How do you expect it to behave? What is the unexpected behavior you're seeing?